# How to get weights for rbf kernel or any custom kernel in SVM?

Tags: kernel, svm, linear-regression

i need to get the weights from a sklearn svm fitted with a custom kernel or rbf kernel. i saw that dual_coeff gives few values but not sure how to use them.

thanks in advance.